# Is it possible to stay in a palace in Jaipur?

Tags: india, accommodation, hotels, jaipur

I have been told that it is possible in some parts of India to stay in a former palace.  Is it possible in or near Jaipur, Rajasthan, India?  How can I reliably book a stay before arriving in India?

Comment: Besides the above answer, there's [an entire section on the Taj hotels group website for former palaces turned into hotels](http://www.tajhotels.com/luxury/grand-palaces-and-iconic-hotels/default.html). (Taj is one of the biggest upscale/luxury hotel chains in India. They own most of the palace-turned-hotel options.)

Answer (score 5):

[Through booking.com](http://www.booking.com/hotel/in/rambagh-palace.en-us.html) you can reliably book accommodation in most countries of the world, including several palace-hotels in Jaipur.

In this case, the link is for Hotel Rambagh Palace, in Jaipur.